# I can't permanently add icons to the top bar anymore- they disappear upon reboot

Tags: 10.04, gnome-panel

I accidentally deleted the top bar and now it will not save icons that I add to it.

I'll spend 5 minutes adding icons back only to find they disappear upon rebooting.

This has to be the strangest, glitchiest OS I've ever used.  The icons are randomly changing positions on the bar, sometimes are half drawn or not at all, or spaced out unusually, or not there at all.  What the heck?  I just want a bar with my icons that doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the top panel and add a new one again

Comment: @WebDeveloper I recommend you edit this answer to explain how to do that. If you wish, you could even include one or more screenshots (*in addition* to descriptive text).

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your gnome panels to the defaults by typing the following in a terminal;

```
gconftool-2 --shutdown 
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel 
pkill gnome-panel
```

The panels will then be as they were when you first installed - you will loose any custom settings.

If you would like to use a GUI for this you can install a program called Panelrestore, it also gives you the option to back up your panel settings. Details on how to install and use it can be [found here](http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/easily-restore-the-default-gnome-panels-in-ubuntu/) .